# Does django automatically handle auto-escaping & context aware?

Tags: python, django, security, xss

As now I am developing website using django web framework of python.

I have very concerned with XSS & security of website.

I have read some references related XSS & prevent them using escaping , encoding etc..

so my question is does Django autoescape every input data & handle XSS attacks automatically or explicitly do we need to implement code to prevent XSS attack ?

How can we prevent all kinds of XSS attacks in Django ?

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/27805/is-djangos-built-in-security-enough TL;DR: It won't do the whole job, but the it'll protect against the majority if you set it up right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think auto-escaping is enabled in Django by default:

https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/AutoEscaping

Unless you are using custom template tags, you have to explicitly mark tags as "safe" (or by using "autoescape off") to not auto-escape them:  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatefilter-safe

Answer (score 0):

upto some point django handles some attacks but to handle more django documentation helps https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/security/

Comment: Answers that contains only links will be delete in future so please post your answers with code and its explanation.